# How to differentiate if the command was incorrect or the result is empty for nodejs child_process.execSync

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
try {
    var output = child_process.execSync(cmd);
} catch (ex) {
    return 0
}
return output.toString()
```

so I want to differentiate the cases when cmd="lx -a", which is a incorrect command and the case when cmd="ls /home/dir", and /home/dir is a empty directory, so it will generate nothing or empty string.
When I tried it, it seems both cases will be caught by nodejs as exception.

How to differentiate? I thought I can write code like

```
if (ex.message.indexOf("not found") >= 0)
```

But it will only cover one case when the command itself is incorrect, what if the parameter is wrong? Or other situations when the error message does not include "not found"?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for the method:

> If the process times out, or has a non-zero exit code, this method
>   will throw. The `Error` object will contain the entire result from
>   `child_process.execSync()`.

So, in case of the non-existent command - it will throw an Error.
Otherwise it will return an empty string in `output`. 
Set `output` to `undefined` before the `try`, so you could check it for the case of trowing an error.

Answer (score 0):

try to use switch case for your positive cases and use the default for any other values of cmd and in default, you can return your custom values.